# Semaphore error in Linux - :Invalid argument error no :22 (EINVAL)

Tags: linux, semaphore

I am trying to execute a C program in linux and I am getting error as "P_Semaphore :Invalid argument error no :22," can someone help

```
Int P_Semaphore(int i_sem_id)
{
 int i_code_returns;
 struct sembuf t_semop;
 #ifdef TRACE
 Debug(N_DEBUG_8, "P_Semaphore", "Entree, i_sem_id=%d<<<<<<\n", i_sem_id);
 #endif
 t_semop.sem_num = 0;
 t_semop.sem_op  = -1;
 t_semop.sem_flg = 0;
 do
 {
   i_code_retour = semop(i_sem_id, &t_semop, 0);

 } while ((i_code_returns == KO) && (errno == EINTR));

 if (i_code_retour == KO)
 {
   printf( "%s(%d):Error semaphore making attempt %d,errno = %d\n", M_HEADER, i_sem_id, errno);
  perror("P_Semaphore");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual on semop(2)

```
   EINVAL The semaphore set doesn't exist, or semid is less than zero,
          or nsops has a nonpositive value.
```

So in your case, `nsops` is zero (non-positive). It should be one.

This is the third parameter of the call:

```
int semop(int semid, struct sembuf *sops, size_t nsops);
```

Comment: I checked , the semaphore set exists, also with a positive value

Comment: nsops is the third parameter to the semop call. It is zero and it should be 1.

Comment: no its not the problem I checked,  I am getting error in the printf statement " printf( "%s(%d):Error semaphore making attempt %d,errno = %d\n", M_HEADER, i_sem_id, errno); "

Comment: Please look again. The third parameter in your semop call is wrong.

Comment: You should up-vote and accept an answer when it correctly identifies the issue in your code. Then others who have the same problem can also benefit from your question and you can gain reputation points in the process.